# How do I prevent automatic browser page refreshment done by Javascript?

Tags: browser-addons, website, javascript, userscripts, advertisements

There are some news websites which automatically and periodically refresh their page just in order to show the user more advertisement. If you are watching a video, all the buffered stream is gone when it refreshes the page. Or, when you are reading a text, it is really disturbing to have a page refreshment.

I believe that most of these evil people use Javascript to refresh the page. Is there any extension or userscript for solving this. The tool must prevent any page refreshment action which is attempted without user interaction (like clicking a submit button, or pressing F5). I'm using both Chrome and Firefox, I need solutions for both of these browsers.

Comment: It might not be javascript as the answer says. But if it is, you can turn off javascript for that site only. Both chrome and firefox has the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not always a JavaScript action. In most of cases it is a HTML Meta content assured by this tag:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5000">`

You can maybe edit it, using FireBug or a Client Side HTML editor, and delete this tag (if exists).

Answer (score 0):

If it's JavaScript, [notscripts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn) and [noscript](http://noscript.net/) will allow you to control what JavaScripts load in Chrome or Firefox. However, video may require allowing scripts to run.