# Disabling web page auto reload

Tags: firefox, browser, website

Some web pages have an auto-reload feature and there's no way to disable it in the web page.
This is specially annoying if you are reading and suddenly the page reloads and move the text or if you are watching a video and the video stops due to the auto-reload feature.

There's any way to disable this feature without messing up with the web page code?

Comment: See if this works>>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/423411/how-do-i-prevent-automatic-browser-page-refreshment-done-by-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `accessibility.blockautorefresh` option.

Open a new window on Firefox and type `about:config` on the address bar

Then search for the term *autorefresh* and you should see the option, set it to `true` so it will block the auto refresh feature

Finally restart Firefox

Comment: In some sites work others don't.

Comment: hmm in that case I am not so sure, it may be that some sites are reloading the page via javascript in which case you'd need a javascript blocker or to turn it off altogether, sorry I can't help out more!